# How to filter uvm_info messages by type_id?

Tags: verilog, uvm

I need to filter all the uvm_info log messages by the type_id defined in it. For example, if I want to display only the uvm_info messages from a driver or a monitor, how can I effectively do it?

Answer (score 2):

The UVM does not provide a mechanism to do this very easily. You would have to set the verbosity of everything to `UVM_NONE` from the top-level down, then go back and turn on just the messages from the drivers and monitors.

Finding al the drivers and monitors might also be difficult unless you gave specific component names, like starting with "drv" and "mon". Then you could use `uvm_root::find_all("drv*",comps);` and set the verbosity of those components in `comps` back to `UVM_FULL`.

It might be easier just to take the entire log file and filter the results you want using a (sed/awk/perl/python) script

Answer (score -1):

How about a custom report catcher?

https://verificationacademy.com/verification-methodology-reference/uvm/docs_1.1d/html/files/base/uvm_report_catcher-svh.html

You can put this in your base test or top, then perhaps control this using a plusarg. A rudimentary example is here:

https://edaplayground.com/x/b4Fx

Answer (score -2):

I think I am quite late to answer this question, however some time ago I wrote a program to filter UVM logs: https://github.com/Loneknight73/uvmlogfilter .
You can filter on, e.g., severity, id, time, component hierarchy and the message text.
That should help anyone who needs to filter verbose UVM logs.